# Access value from Json object containing list

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm hoping someone has come across this problem also. I'm a newbie to all this, therefore excuse my lack of knowledge in advance.

I want to access list of object and to store in a array. can anyone help me how to access the value as i am having json like: -

```
device = {
     "macAddress" : "00:00:00:00:00:00",
     "route" : [{"lat" : 28.35 , "lng" : 78.325},
                {"lat" : 28.35 , "lng" : 78.325},
                {"lat" : 28.35 , "lng" : 78.325},
                {"lat" : 28.35 , "lng" : 78.325} ]
}
```

i want to get the value of route in an array i have tried using device.route but it is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

device is an JSON object which further contain "route" array and route array contains further Json objects. you can access like :

```
var value=device.Route[1].lat;
```

Comment: @Harsh Batham this will work for you. if you want to access macaddress the code will be device.macAddress;

Answer (score 0):

what do mean `device.route` not accessible. its perfectly fine

```js
var device = {
         "macAddress" : "00:00:00:00:00:00",
         "route" : [{"lat" : 28.35 , "lng" : 78.325},
                    {"lat" : 28.35 , "lng" : 78.325},
                    {"lat" : 28.35 , "lng" : 78.325},
                    {"lat" : 28.35 , "lng" : 78.325} ]

} 

var routeArr = device.route;

console.log(routeArr);
```

if you wand to get one object from route array then access the array by index

`device.route[0]`

```js
var device = {
         "macAddress" : "00:00:00:00:00:00",
         "route" : [{"lat" : 28.35 , "lng" : 78.325},
                    {"lat" : 28.35 , "lng" : 78.325},
                    {"lat" : 28.35 , "lng" : 78.325},
                    {"lat" : 28.35 , "lng" : 78.325} ]

} 

var routeArr = device.route[0];

console.log(routeArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
var device = {
   "macAddress" : "00:00:00:00:00:00",
   "route" : [
      {"lat" : 28.35 , "lng" : 78.325},
      {"lat" : 28.35 , "lng" : 78.325},
      {"lat" : 28.35 , "lng" : 78.325},
      {"lat" : 28.35 , "lng" : 78.325} 
   ]
}

console.log(device.route);   //OR
console.log(device["route"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the whole array value of route. It can be simple obtained by 
***device.route***.

For individual index values inside the array you can do so by ***device.route[index]***.

For values inside object of the array. It can be obtained by ***device.route[0]["lat"]*** or ***device.route[0].lat***.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I want the whole array value but as i console this it give me undefined.